# plotting with different color between old and updated data

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I reformulated my question and hope it is a bit clearer now:

```
         Here is my data:
            ID  Type        X               Y       Sex
            a1  Test    -12.12609861    208.6810478 XY
            a2  Test    -1.32366642     63.0574351  XXY
            a3  Test    -9.02867948     114.1501293 XY
            b4  NewTest 0.01101428      0.87207664  XX
            b5  Test    -1.14651604     -0.86714741 XX
            b6  Test    -13.05848944    155.5109551 XY
            x7  NewTest -4.74479593     80.82528931 XY
            x8  Test    -8.17386444     124.4765311 XY
            x9  Test    1.14870262      -0.36606683 XX
            x10 Test    1.20879037      0.80972607  XX
            x11 Test    -1.04261274     0.35654895  XX
            x12 Test    -11.73602       185.5326725 XY
```

I would like to plot the data with different color according to whether the data is new or old.
The new data is added daily or weekly so the color change needs to be dynamic. N.B the new data always start with "newTest" in the column "TYPE"

The code:

```
     for_loop_start<- (nrow(whole_data)-1)
            len_of_whole_data<- nrow(whole_data)
            for (j in c(for_loop_start:1)){

              if (whole_data[j,2] == "NewTest"){

                break
              }

            }
            new_data <- with(whole_data,whole_data[j:len_of_whole_data,])
  > p <- ggplot(data=whole_data,aes(x=X,y=Y)) +  geom_point(colour = "black")
  > ggplotly(p)
  > p <- p + geom_point(data= new_data,
              mapping=aes(x=X,y=Y,text=SampleID,colour = "darkgoldenrod2"))
  > ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: @Mikko  I changed how the data looks like to reflect my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to edited version of the question**

If the last "NewType" value in your "Type" column consistently starts "new data", this should work:

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "b4", "b5", 
"b6", "x10", "x11", "x12", "x7", "x8", "x9"), class = "factor"), 
    Type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("NewTest", "Test"), class = "factor"), 
    X = c(-12.12609861, -1.32366642, -9.02867948, 0.01101428, 
    -1.14651604, -13.05848944, -4.74479593, -8.17386444, 1.14870262, 
    1.20879037, -1.04261274, -11.73602), Y = c(208.6810478, 63.0574351, 
    114.1501293, 0.87207664, -0.86714741, 155.5109551, 80.82528931, 
    124.4765311, -0.36606683, 0.80972607, 0.35654895, 185.5326725
    ), Sex = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("XX", "XXY", "XY"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Type", "X", "Y", "Sex"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

lim.id <- max(which(dat$Type == "NewTest")) - 1

dat$Age <- c(rep("old", lim.id), rep("new", nrow(dat) - lim.id))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=X, y=Y, color = Age)) + geom_point() +
scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgoldenrod2", "black"))
```

[image]

**Old answer**

You could try to make a script that reads the modification time (see `?file.mtime`) and use that to make a column, which specifies whether the entry is "new" or "old"

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:12, Type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("control", "Test"
), class = "factor"), X = c(-12.12609861, -1.32366642, -9.02867948, 
0.01101428, -1.14651604, -13.05848944, -4.74479593, -8.17386444, 
1.14870262, 1.20879037, -1.04261274, -11.73602), Y = c(208.6810478, 
63.0574351, 114.1501293, 0.87207664, -0.86714741, 155.5109551, 
80.82528931, 124.4765311, -0.36606683, 0.80972607, 0.35654895, 
185.5326725), Sex = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("XX", "XXY", "XY"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Type", "X", "Y", "Sex"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

dat$Time <- seq(as.Date("2017-07-12"), as.Date("2017-06-12"), length = nrow(dat))
dat$Time.type <- ifelse(as.Date(Sys.time()) - dat$Time < 12, "new", "old")

library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(dat, aes(x=X, y=Y, color = Time.type)) + geom_point() +
scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "darkgoldenrod2"))
```

Comment: Thank you @Mikko. Actually I was thinking about that solution but  as I said before I wanted to make the change dynamic because I can't know for sure the date when the new data was/to be  added that is why I was thinking the only way to know that is to start from bottom up and once we find "control" in the column TYPE that means the new added data start from there. N.B the new data always start with "control" in the column "TYPE"

Comment: @Alexis_543. The solution above is "dynamic" in a sense that if you run the code in 12 days, all points will get "old" tag and plotted as yellow points. If you know the cut point at all times, you can use subset as @rashid suggested. Just make that `lim.id` change and then `ifelse(dat$ID < lim.id, "old", "new")`

Comment: I think this could work perfectly if for sure the new data is added every predefined period otherwise if we added new_data1 and new_data2 within the last 12 days, in the plot (new_data1 and new_data2) will be in Black, right? whereas I want only the last new data (new_data2 in this run) in Black no matter when it was added

Comment: thank you this is something I was looking but since my original data is way too large (over 10000 row). Is there a way to automaticcaly assign the attribute to dat from the loaded data from excel? this is how I loaded my data from excel to r: wb = loadWorkbook("data.xlsx")
df = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", header = TRUE)
#df
whole_data<-df

Comment: @Alexis_543: which attribute are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

you could also just set a variable which defines on which ID to split your dataframe for plotting (supposing df1 is your dataframe):

```
lim.id <- 7 #here you can put whatever value you would like to split your data.frame on
plot1 <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = df1[df1$ID < lim.id, ], aes(x = X, y = Y), colour =  "black")
plot1 <- plot1 +
    geom_point(data = df1[df1$ID >= lim.id, ], aes(x = X, y = Y), colour = "darkgoldenrod2")
plot2 <- ggplotly(plot2)
```

Comment: Thank you  @rashid for your reply but I think that is not what I would like to have because in the next update the ids will change and I need to recode every time there is a new data added

Comment: Hello Alexis. You would like to not have to change your script whenever new data is added, right? Do the values of the ids change?

Comment: Yes, no change to script every time new data added and Yes the ids change every time new data is added

Comment: Well, I guess there needs to be some way to find which are the newly added IDs. I would then go with Mikkos solution.